# What do you call a flexible rubber boot that protects wires?

Tags: cables, wire, ribbon-cable, ffc, small-gauge-wire

I'm not sure if this is the correct site to post it on, but it seemed closest related to electronics.

I'm diy-ing a laptop and I have a couple of 15-pin FFCs that have to be flexed a little over 100 degrees (not a completely sharp bend though) in one direction when the laptop is opened. I'd like to provide some extra protection to the wires from the elements and whatnot, as it will be a ruggedized type laptop, as well as give the cable some extra rigidity so that it reduces the chance of it being pinched upon closing.

What I'm looking for is a (preferably) rectangular rubber boot protector which is 'collapsible', like the type found between a car door and the frame. Is this/what is the correct term? I can't find much on google except for some (round) cable end stress relievers.

Edit- sorta like this thingy:
[image]

Comment: insulating boots....

Comment: @BrianDrummond sorry all I'm getting from that term is insulating boots for spark plugs and footwear... maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? I'm still a beginner in electronics so I'm not sure where to look or what terms to use.

Comment: IMO, unlikely that you will find that for FFCs

Comment: @WesleyLee I thought so, but what if I took a "normal" round boot and twisted the FFC to fit in it? Would it be damaged by trying to bend it? Or I think I've seen others split the FFC lengthwise, but only through the center (so that it can still be connected properly), and put the "strips" together in a boot?

Comment: the display cable may be less prone to breakage it it rotates and twists along the cable axis

Comment: Have you tried "grommet" as a search term, with "square" and "sleeved"?

Comment: @jsotola If I understand you correctly, that is my plan, so that the flat end of the cable is parallel to the flat face of the display. I just wanted some extra protection.

Comment: They tend to be small scale production : a place I worked had a custom boot made by a local firm, by dipping a mould into liquid rubber. Ask some local manufacturers of the boots you CAN find if they'd be willing to make to your design, or design ote to your spec.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I began thinking about that, and actually found a listing with a square boot close to what I needed, but then remembered that I could probably 3d print one with a flexible filament like Ninjaflex. While it looks like DIY seems like the way to go, I still don't know what to call these darn things... :D

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=self+fusing+silicone+electrical+tape&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @Galaxy I was talking about routing the cable along the laptop display hinge axis, so that it does not bend ... it twists instead ... https://www.diypcrepairs.xyz/dell-inspiron-9300/images/4242_77_70-computer-cable-routing.jpg

Comment: I would call it a "strain relief" gland/boot

Comment: @mhaselup that's that I would think, but it only gives me the one-ended grommets on the ends of power cords